# How to append a string to another string having multiple lines and terminated by the backslash character

Tags: javascript, string

I would like to append the string variable to the another string. Second string is having large number of characters with the multiple lines and seperated by the backslash character("\").

I am looking for solution in javascript

for example

```
var one = 'test string one'; 

var two = 'test string two\
              is seperated by back slash and this string has\
              multiple number of lines';
```

Now i want to append string one to the string two as below

```
var two = 'test string two'+one+\
              is seperated by back slash and this string has\
              multiple number of lines';
```

I am looking for append first string with the second string. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to start the strig literal again with a `'` :

```
'test string two' + one + '\
 is seperated by back slash and this string has\
 multiple number of lines';
```

Or you use template strings, then you dont need the newlines at all:

```
`test string two ${one}
 is seperated by back slash and this string has
 multiple number of lines`
```

Comment: i can have in my second string as below  '<div style="dd">\ 
                                                                   </div>'

Comment: @nalla yes you can

Comment: Can`t we do it with backslash instead of  " ` "?. I am looking for the backslash